How to ensure my Python dependencies in the cPanel Application Manager execute successfully
When I want to "Ensure dependencies" for my Python application, I get the following error message:
The system couldn’t ensure dependencies for your application. For more information, see the instructions below. The process failed. Run the following command from the command line:

cd /home/henridev/dummy && /usr/bin/pip3.6 install --user -r requirements.txt

I can manually configure my Virtual Environment from the Terminal and successfully install all the dependencies.
However, when trying to access my app from a website browser, an error still arises in which my modules cannot be successfully imported.  For example:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'uvicorn'

Is suspect this is because the "Ensure dependencies" still doesn't execute successfully despite a manual configuration of the Python Virtual Environment.
In cPanel, I only have "Application Manager" available. NOT the "Setup Python App" functionality. Matters are complicated by the fact that uvicorn requires at least Python 3.8 to run successfully. However, the latest Python3 version in my usr/bin is Python3.6.
On the other hand, I also tried:
echo 'source scl_source enable rh-python38' >> ~/.bashrc
echo 'source scl_source enable rh-python38' >> ~/.bash_profile

to ensure that every shell session uses Python3.8 as the default Python3 interpreter. But this did not resolve the problem.
